# Taxonomy view to display all terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I am using the default taxonomy view that comes with the views module and everything is working as expected. The one problem I have is that I cannot figure out how to display a page showing all nodes under my parent vocabulary term.

Vocabulary = videos

```
-Term 1
--Term A

-Term 2
--Term A

-Term 3
--Term A
```

So with the example above if I go to any of the terms I will get the terms and children associated with them. Ex: www.site.com/videos/term-1. That works.

But I would like to have a view listing ALL of the nodes when a user goes to www.site.com/videos.

It's gotta be pretty simple, but I am missing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view of taxonomy terms with a contextual filter of the type **Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name**

Add relationship called **Taxonomy term: Content with term** and use that relationship to add the contents.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. I was trying to make this work with the same view, but I ended up creating another view like you said and that works. :)