# Add a view for all nodes by vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I need to display nodes in a *dynamic* view, **based on their vocabulary** and not a single term. For example, for car sales, one vocabulary lets the visitor select one model, and another selects the color.

My custom path looks like this:

```
/sales/cars/%            // vocabulary view
/sales/cars/%            // vocabulary view

/sales/cars/models/%     // taxonomy term view   (works !)
/sales/cars/colors/%     // taxonomy term view   (works !)
```

URL example:

```
/sales/cars/models       // all nodes with a term from models vocabulary
/sales/cars/colors       // all nodes with a term from colors vocabulary
```

I've tried a [solution from a similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58724/taxonomy-view-to-display-all-terms), but I can not *find* a Contextual Filter called:

> Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name

Comment: add a relationship:  `Content: Taxonomy terms on node` and select vocabularies which you want to use. Then `Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name` filter will be available.

Comment: @cept0, please comment on your original question instead of opening a new one for the same problem.  Thanks!